# Integral of $\sec^3(x)$

Tags: calculus

I want to find the integral of $\sec^3(x)$, but I don't know what to do.  I tried a double integration by parts to try and solve it in terms of itself, but I ended up getting 0=0.  Could I just have a hint, please?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** $$\int\sec^3(x)dx =\int  \sec(x)(\tan^2(x)+1)dx =\int \tan^2(x)\sec(x)dx+\int\sec(x)dx$$